# Detect Click event inside ngx bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have implemented a ngx bootstrap modal following this guide - https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#bs-modal-service. but when the modal is opened how can i detect any click events inside the modal body. I have the below code in my app component.

I have tried this with viewChild but when I am clicking inside the modal after it is opened always returns undefined.

**App Component HTML -**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Create template modal</button>

<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" #modalBody>
    This is a modal.
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**App Component ts -**

```
import { Component, TemplateRef, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  host: {
  '(document:click)': 'closemodal($event)'
  }
})

export class AppComponent mplements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('modalBody', { static : false}) modalBody : ElementRef;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }


  closemodal(event : any) {
    if (!this.modalBody.nativeElement.contains(event.target)){
       console.log('clicked in the modal')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code where you used `ViewChild`?

Comment: @Ramesh i have updated the code please check and let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: Instead of listening to modal click, listen to `document ` click and filter out based on `event-target`, just make sure when you are closing the modal  you are not listening back to those events because it is on `document`

Comment: @Monis Can you be able share some example?

Comment: ```this.document.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
    console.log(event.target) // just target your classes 
})
```
This is not a very elegant way, but  one of the work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is the issue with binding a event handler directly in the modal body DOM. Try the following

Template

```html
<button style="margin: 10px" type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="openModal(template)">Create template modal</button>

<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <span style="cursor: pointer" (mouseup)="textClick($event)">Some sample text</span>
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClick($event)">Click me</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent {
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }

  textClick(event: any) {
    console.log('text clicked inside modal body');
  }

  onClick(event: any) {
    console.log('button clicked inside modal body');
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-modal-vgrm2c)